# find url from a text and open that url in new tab

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model Image and every image is having description. User can add links in that description. Now while displaying that description I want link to display as normal link and should open in new tab.

Sample description can be:

Hey, thats sample text, you can find more photos at google.com

user can enter url like:

google.com, 
www.google.com, 
http://google.com, 
http://www.google.com etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [auto_html](https://github.com/dejan/auto_html) gem for a similar use case. Say you have the text which contains the urls in variable `text` then you can do something like:

```
auto_html(text) do
  html_escape
  link :target => "_blank", :rel => "nofollow"
end
```